# Image expension causes brightness descrease

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to implement an image expansion using the following algorithm:

```
1. Zero pad: Put a zero pixel between two pixels
2. Convolve with a column vector of a Gaussian, and multiply by 2
3. Convolve with a row vector of a Gaussian and multiply by 2
4. Return blurred image.
```

Here is the code I used (I used 3 for the guassian size):

```
def expand(im, filter_size):
   ''' Takes an image and expands it. '''

    # zero - pad
    new_image_shape = (im.shape[0]*2,im.shape[1]*2)

    zero_image = np.zeros(new_image_shape)

    zero_image[1::2,1::2] = im

    padded_image = zero_image

    gaussian = gaussian_kernel(filter_size)
    im_blured_x = ndimage.filters.convolve(padded_image, 2*gaussian)

    transpose = gaussian.transpose()
    im_blured = ndimage.filters.convolve(im_blured_x,2*transpose)


    return im_blured
```

The following are the original and expanded image respectively:

Original:

[image]

Expanded:

[image]

This is the implementation of the gaussian_kernel, but I already verified that for kernel_size=3 it gives [0.25,0.75,0.25]:

```
def gaussian_kernel(kernel_size):
    ''' Takes a kernel size that is odd and returns a 2D gaussian
    kernel of this size. Results are undefined for even sizes.
    Arguments:
        kernel_size - The size of the kernel, an odd integer.
    Returns:
        gaussian - A normalized gaussian kernel of given size.
    '''
    if kernel_size == 1:
        return np.array([0,1,0],dtype='float32')
    # Create a gaussian kernel
    gaussian = np.array([1,1],dtype='float32')
    # Convolve it with itself kernel_size times
    convolved = gaussian

    num_of_convolutions = kernel_size-2
    for i in range(0,num_of_convolutions):
        convolved = np.convolve(convolved,gaussian)

    # Normalize it
    sum = convolved.sum()
    nor_gaussian = np.divide(convolved,sum,dtype='float32')


    return np.array([nor_gaussian,]).astype(np.float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ndimage.filters.convolve without a "mode" argument, it uses "reflect" by default, which seems to mean it reflects the values close to the end of the picture, and this seems to cause problems. Using "mode=constant" instead fixed the issue.

Comment: in which line are you using "mode=constant" ? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: That was the problem. When one adds mode="constant" tot the convolutions the problem gets resolved.